# Machi Koro Millionaire's Row Moving Company and renovation questions

Tags: machi-koro

I have two rule clarifications that we've run into that we haven't been able to find an answer to while playing the [Millionaire's Row](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/160154/machi-koro-millionaires-row) expansion of Machi Koro:

1. Can you use a Moving Company to move itself?
2. Is a renovation token removed from cards when the number is rolled but they don't do anything. For instance, a Corn Field activates on 3-4, but only if you have less than 2 monuments. Would a renovation token be removed from a Corn Field if 4 was rolled but the player had 2 or more monuments?

Comment: Is this about an expansion or spinoff?

Comment: Both of those cards are from expansions, I just don't remember which ones.

Comment: "Moving Company" and the renovation tokens are introduced in the Millionaire's Row expansion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Note for the Moving Company card in the rules](http://idwgames.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Machi-Mil-RULES-digital.pdf)

> The Moving Company can be given to other players

So the answer to the first part of your question is "yes."

The same rules also say

> The next time a rollwould activate this Establishment and earn income, remove the token instead ...

They go on to give some examples of how card color (activating on your own rolls or other player rolls) behave. In the example you provided, the Corn field would *not* activate and earn income, therefor the renovation marker remains.

It makes sense if you think of it as the next round of income for the card paying for the required renovations and re-opening the establishment. If it never earns any income, the renovations never happen.